# Weird usage of てしまう

Tags: nuances

> 巨人は豆の木から落ちて**死んでしまいました**。

I've learned that てしまう is used for either **complete** or **unintentional** actions. In this example, they're using it with the verb 死ぬ (to die). I'm confused because I feel like none of these are applicable. Either:

1. *He died completely*. But how can you die "not completely"?
2. *He died unintentionally*. But when do you ever die intentionally (other than suicide). This would mean we have to use てしまう every time we use 死ぬ, because most of the time people die unintentionally.

My guess is that it's reinforcing point #2 and gives a certain nuance. Could someone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`てしまう` can has the meaning of something bad, happened, unintentionally, in this case, dying is a bad thing. And the writer/speaker will use `しまう` to express his/her feeling towards what ever happened.
`彼が死んだ`, `彼が死んでしまった`。Both means the same `He's dead`, but the latter has the meaning of the speaker feels bad about it.